# Send a rest response instead of a HTML Page when javax.validation.constraints.* is not met

Tags: java, spring, rest, validation, post

I am building a Spring REST service, and i have a bunch of endpoints which take a request payload via the POST method. I have included JSR 303 spec in my project and it works fine for validations. Now how do i make my application send an JSON response back along with a different status code. At present the Application gives a 400 with a tomcat error page.

[image: Error from the application]

Update:

I figured out that i need to include BindingResult in my method and hence i can extract the errors from there.

```
@PostMapping(value = "/validateBankInformation", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
protected ResponseEntity<BusinessSolutionVO> validateBankInformation(@Valid @RequestBody BankInformation bankInformation, BindingResult bindingResult) {
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        List<ObjectError> errors = bindingResult.getAllErrors();
        for (ObjectError error : errors) {
            System.out.println(error.getDefaultMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you done so far?

Answer (score 0):

Is your entity class annotated correctly?

You must define the `UniqueConstraints` inside the `@Table` annotation.

```
@Table(uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "username" }),
    @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "email" }), @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "field1", "field2" }) })
public class User implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Email
    @NotNull
    private String email;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 4, max = 24)
    private String username;

    @NotNull
    private String password;

    @NotNull
    private String field1;

    @NotNull
    private String field2;

    // Getters
    // Setters
    // Other Methods

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to solve this. But the simplest one for this case is to return the http error response like below:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/validateBankInformation", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
protected ResponseEntity<BusinessSolutionVO> validateBankInformation(@Valid @RequestBody BankInformation bankInformation, BindingResult bindingResult) {

    if (bindingResult.hasFieldErrors()) {
           String errors = bindingResult.getFieldErrors().stream()
                    .map(p -> p.getDefaultMessage()).collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));            
                //throw new InvalidRequestParameterException("Bad Request", errors);

           return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(errors);
     }

     return ResponseEntity.ok("Successful");
}
```

Or you can create custom exception messages and throw them.